# Regex for not empty and not whitespace

Tags: regex, whitespace

I am trying to create a regex that will return false if the String pattern contains whitespace or is empty. So far I have this

```
[^\s]
```

I think that will make sure the string does not contain whitespace but I am unsure of how to also check to make sure it is not empty. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `str.length() == 0 || str.contains(" ")` for this.

Comment: @NarendraYadala, this will not match on tabs and other [whitespace characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`/^$|\s+/` if this matched, there's whitespace or its empty.

Comment: Correct. the + isn't needed. Just do not put a * there. ;)

Comment: In some languages (e.g. Ruby), `^` and `$` mean begining or end of the line, not string.  But interesting fact is that even under this circumstances the expression will work correctly.

Comment: @skalee There's a PCRE Modifier "m" which toggles multiline support

Comment: @Jan Yes, but this regexp will work correctly even without this modifier because /^$/ will either match empty string or empty line in multiline string. And empty line => there's line break somewhere => whitespace.

Comment: In my case `/^$|\s+/  =~ "      "`  return 0

why ?

Comment: @GiorgioDesideri You should ask it on a new question, looks interesting why.

Comment: how would you invert this? I want it match if the string is not whitespace or empty

Comment: And How to avoid not empty string pls help me i have used following regex (?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])(?=\\S+$).{8,15}

Comment: Please note that in PHP/PCRE this will need the `u` modifier to properly recognize [unicode whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode).

Answer (score 72):

In my understanding you want to match a non-blank and non-empty string, so the top answer is doing the opposite. I suggest:

```
(.|\s)*\S(.|\s)*
```

This matches any string containing at least one non-whitespace character (the `\S` in the middle). It can be preceded and followed by anything, any character or whitespace sequence (including new lines): `(.|\s)*`.

You can try it with explanation on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xZZRSC/1).

Comment: After trying all of the varying answers I've found for this question, this one worked for me!

Comment: I too don't understand why this isn't the best answer. It matches perfectly what the OP question asked for.

Comment: after some years it's time to answer that. it's easier and shorter to do it that way, also the condition is positive. It's good practice to formulate your conditions in a positive way and not in a negative. Note that a REGULAR EXPRESSION does not return anything. So the demand that a RE should return `false` is not fulfillable if you nitpick..

Comment: Thank you! I agree that the top answer is doing the opposite of what is asked.

Answer (score 26):

Most regular expression engines support "counter part" escape sequences. That is, for `\s` (white-space) there's its counter part `\S` (non-white-space).

Using this, you can check, if there is at least one non-white-space character with `^\S+$`.

PCRE for PHP [has several of these escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

Comment: The regex is good, but the explanation is a bit misleading. Your regex matches a string that consists entirely of non-whitespace characters and is at least one character in length. Thus, it does more than just "check if there is at least one non-whitespace character".

Comment: Why the downvote? The regex is solving the OP's problem - if it matches, the string is not empty and doesn't contain whitespace.

Comment: This was the one for me. I simply did `str.match(/\S+/)`

Comment: I tested this regex for the OP's request. It allows empty strings. They want to also exclude empty strings

Comment: @Richard I just tested this on several engines and it seems the simplest approach. It's also used extensively as a regex for covering exactly this case (match a string non-empty, non-whitespace) in e.g. wazuh. How does it allow empty strings, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 12):

`/^$|\s+/`
This matches when empty or white spaces

`/(?!^$)([^\s])/`
This matches when its not empty or white spaces

Answer (score 6):

I ended up using something similar to the accepted answer, with minor modifications

```
(^$)|(\s+$)
```

Explanation by the [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)

```
Select from 2 alternatives (^$)
    [1] A numbered captured group ^$
        Beginning of line ^
        End of line $
    [2] A numbered captured group (\s+$)
        Whitespace, one or more repetitions \s+
        End of line $
```

Comment: You'll probably also want to mark these as non-capturing groups:
`(?:^$)|(?:\s+$)`

Answer (score 6):

A little late, but here's a regex I found that returns 0 matches for empty or white spaces:

```
/^(?!\s*$).+/
```

You can test this out at [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 0):

`/^[\s]*$/` matches empty strings and strings containing whitespaces only

Comment: That's not what medium asked for.

Comment: You can remove the square brackets there. `/^\s*$/` will do the same task.

Comment: @Narendra: Yes, but the question was to find strings that *contain* whitespace characters somewhere, not just *consist* of whitespace characters.

Comment: @TimPietzcker I see. Then `/^$|\s/` makes more sense as you pointed above. But I am not sure why would OP use regex for that, as `String` methods such as `str.length == 0 || str.contains(" ")`  would be more handy in that case.

Comment: @Narendra: The question "why regex?" is probably one of the most-asked questions in comments here on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate regex for a non-blank and non-empty string should be

```
(.|\n)*\S(.|\n)*
```

This prevents catastrophic backtracking that

```
(.|\s)*\S(.|\s)*
```

has with `.` and `\s` having overlapping matching. This shows at [regex101](https://regex101.com/) with a test string of even just 20 or so space characters.