# how to check that tag does not contain spaces or null as value using regular expression

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to validate a string (containg numbers, alphabets and spaces in between words and also contains trailing and leading white spaces) .I need a regular expression which i can put in response assertion of jmeter

Comment: asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967075/regex-for-not-empty-and-not-whitespace you can use /^$|\s+/ in regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Standard recommendation [not to use regular expressions for working with HTML and/or XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748).

---

Go for [XPath Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Assertion) instead, using it you can implement your requirement using XPath query like:

```
//yourElement[@yourTag!='null' and not(contains(@yourTag,' '))]
```

XPath language is quite easy, at least it is much easier to create and read XPath expressions rather than "regular" ones. Check out [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) to get started and [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) guide to learn more about assertions available in JMeter.