# How to check contents inside brackets in pandas

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

I need an expression which checks if there is any content written inside braces ("braces" could be any of `()`, `{}`, `[]`). For Example it should give `True` to these strings:

- `"I am sharad my phone number is (0000000)"`
- `"hi this [sharad]"`
- `"{there} you go"`
- `"[this is error]"`

And should give `False` to:

- `"ho ho ho"`
- `"here comes santa []"`
- `"{} what is this"`

If there is any content inside braces, return `True`, else `False`. I am new to Python thanks for your help in advance.

For example:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file)
df.index = range(2,df.shape[0]+2)
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if(row['column_name']******) # expression to check if there is any 
                                 # content inside brackets content could be 
                                 # nan, string or a number
```

Comment: hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Thank you I did and it surely helped

Comment: Yes, the best is remove question and create another one, also add new tag `regex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with this data:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col' : [
        "I am sharad my phone number is (0000000)",
        "hi this [sharad]",
        "{there} you go",
        "[this is error]",
        "ho ho ho",
        "here comes santa []",
        "{} what is this",
    ]
})

print(df)

                                        col
0  I am sharad my phone number is (0000000)
1                          hi this [sharad]
2                            {there} you go
3                           [this is error]
4                                  ho ho ho
5                       here comes santa []
6                           {} what is this
```

We can check for the "`brackets`" and then check if they contain anything using `regex` and the `contains()` method:

```
print(df.col.str.contains('\[(.+)\]|\((.+)\)|\{(.+)\}'))

0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
Name: col, dtype: bool
```

[Documentation for `contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Explanation for `regex`:

- for the `[]` I used `\[` and `\]` to look for those characters. Then inside of them I used `(.+)` which checks if there is anything between the two brackets.

I did the same using the other two versions of "`brackets`" (`()` and `{}`)

The `|` is an or operator so the `contains` knows to check for any of the `brackets`.

Other resources

- [Regular expression to extract text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403122/regular-expression-to-extract-text-between-square-brackets)
- [Regex for not empty and not whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967075/regex-for-not-empty-and-not-whitespace)

Comment: Thanks a lot man you saved the day!!!

Comment: @SHARADSAURAV you're quite welcome! Was an interesting question.