# Textbox regex validation is not working in uwp

Tags: c#, regex, uwp

This is an example of custom regex validation for numbers only that is provided in official doc of `Windows Community Toolkit` of UWP here [TextBox Regex extensions in toolkit](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WindowsCommunityToolkitDocs/blob/master/docs/extensions/TextBoxRegex.md).

```
<StackPanel Margin="10,0,10,0">
    <TextBox Name="PhoneNumberValidator"
             extensions:TextBoxRegex.Regex="^\s*\+?\s*([0-9][\s-]*){9,}$"
             Header="Text box with Regex extension for phone number, validation occurs on TextChanged"
             HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"
             Style="{StaticResource TextBoxRegexStyle}" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="Is Valid: " />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding (extensions:TextBoxRegex.IsValid), ElementName=PhoneNumberValidator, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}}" />
    </StackPanel>

</StackPanel>
```

It works but if i change the regex and use a custom regex `/^(?!\s*$).+/` for `NotNullOrEmpty` validation then it doesn't work. mean `ext:TextBoxRegex.IsValid` always returns false. Why ?

Comment: Do you use it as in the docs? `extensions:TextBoxRegex.Regex="^(?!\s*$).+"`?

Comment: `xmlns:ext="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Extensions"` yeah same way except i'm using `ext`

Comment: and idk who down voted the question without even saying a single word :(

Comment: What are you trying to match with your `^(?!\s*$).+` RegEx? It is kinda odd to me.

Comment: @bradbury9 sir. from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967075/regex-for-not-empty-and-not-whitespace i got this regex to see if text box text is empty or null

Comment: @bradbury9 idk if you got me or not but that's how it should work in case of Comunity toolkit for Uwp for text box text validation.

Comment: So you didn't use it as in the docs. You must have included the regex delimiters into the regex pattern. The validation is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the regular expression you provided in the WindowsCommunityToolkit Sample App:

```xml
<TextBox extensions:TextBoxRegex.Regex="(?!^$)([^\s])"
         .../>
```

It works fine, that is, after entering text, it shows the result as `True`.

Please note that the regular expression itself does not contain the first and last `/`, it is a syntax that indicates that the internal is a regular expression. When entering the relevant regular expression in XML, you only need to enter the content.